# Slick database access in Actor

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, guice, slick

I have a play-scala application using SqLite with slick. My tables are defined like this:

```
@Singleton
class DataSets @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, keys: PublicKeys) extends DataSetsComponent
  with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
  import driver.api._

  val DataSets = TableQuery[DataSetsTable]

  def all = db.run(DataSets.sortBy { _.id }.result)
  ...
}
```

My controllers get access via DI:

```
@Singleton
class DataSetsController @Inject() (dataSets: DataSets, env: play.Environment) extends Controller {
...
```

How do I get a database handle in an Actor?

```
class TrainActor @Inject() (dataSets: DataSets) extends Actor {
...
```

of course does not work as Guice does not find the DataSets class.

Edit: to clarify: I do not want to use the actor for database access in the controller (via ask), but to start some resource intensive computations from the controller after a request and store them in the db afterwards (async).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now found a way which integrates with DI, closely following the [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-child-actors). Because for the need of an `ActorContext`, `InjectedActorSupport` can only be inherited by `Actor`s. This means I had to create an actor which does nothing than instantiate and start new "worker" Actors. Maybe there is an easier way, but this works correctly.

`TrainActor.scala`:

```
package actors

import javax.inject.Inject

import akka.actor._
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted
import models.{DataSet, Model, PublicKey}
import play.api.Logger
import tables.DataSets

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object TrainActor {
  case object Start
  case class LoadData(d: DataSet, k: PublicKey)

  trait Factory {
    def apply(model: Model): Actor
  }
}

class TrainActor @Inject() (val dataSets: DataSets, @Assisted val model: Model) extends Actor {
  import TrainActor._

  def receive = {
    case Start =>
      dataSets.findWithKey(model.id.get)
      ...
```

`TrainActorStarter.scala`:

```
package actors

import javax.inject.Inject

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef}
import models.Model
import play.api.libs.concurrent.InjectedActorSupport

object TrainActorStarter {
  case class StartTraining(model: Model)
}

/**
  * https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors
  * @param childFactory
  */
class TrainActorStarter @Inject() (childFactory: TrainActor.Factory) extends Actor with InjectedActorSupport {
  import TrainActorStarter._

  def receive = {
    case StartTraining(model: Model) =>
      val trainer: ActorRef = injectedChild(childFactory(model), s"train-model-model-${model.id.get}")
      trainer ! TrainActor.Start
  }
}
```

`ActorModule.scala`:

```
package actors

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

class ActorModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure(): Unit = {
    bindActor[TrainActorStarter]("train-actor-starter")
    bindActorFactory[TrainActor, TrainActor.Factory]
  }
}
```

And finally in the controller:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._

import actors.{TrainActorStarter, TrainCallbackActor}
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, ActorSystem, _}
import akka.stream.Materializer
...

@Singleton
class ModelsController @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer, ..., @Named("train-actor-starter") trainActorStarter: ActorRef) extends Controller with InjectedActorSupport {

  def startTraining(model: Model): Unit = {
    if(model.id.isEmpty) return
    trainActorStarter ! TrainActorStarter.StartTraining(model)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject dependencies into an actor:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaGuiceSupport

class MyModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[TrainActor]("injected-train-actor")
  }
}
```

After that just inject actor into controller:

```
class MyController @Inject()(@Named("injected-train-actor") trainActor: ActorRef) {

  def endpointTest = Action.async {
    for {
      items <- (trainActor ? FetchAll).mapTo[Seq[DataSetsTableRow]]
    } yield Ok(Json.toJson(items))
  }

}
```

Comment: What to do if I want to be able to instantiate new actors in the controller instead of sending messages to one?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having

```
@Singleton
class DataSets
```

one can declare it as a simple scala object that can act as the DataSetsDAO

```
object DataSets
```

and then in the actor just use `DataSets.dbOperation` just bear in mind that the result type of that will be a Future, so just schedule a message to self in the actor on the `onComplete` to avoid any side effects.

Comment: hm I think this would be an easy solution, but then testing is being made impossible

Comment: you can have integration tests running on the test database, otherwise  just pass the injected DataSets instance from the controller via actor Props http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/actors.html#Props